# Is there anyway to use a .model file from Weka in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, weka

I am currently using Weka 3.8 to make a decision tree algorithm in order to properly classify sentences. I was wondering if there is anyway to use the .model file in python as the wrappers i found don't work with Python3 or use an unstable version of Weka. If it is not possible at all to use in python, is there any python library that can build a good decision tree with strings?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using any wrapper you can use system calls and weka commandline:

`java -cp /path/to/weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -T unclassified.arff -l j48.model -p 0`

You need to modify the path of jar file, classifier as well as model and unclassified files.
See https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/making_predictions/ for details.

You can also convert some classifiers to Java source code. If your model is not too complex and doesn't change too much you can port it to python. Check https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/generating_source_code_from_weka_classes/ for details

Answer (score 0):

Weka 3.8 (stable) and Weka 3.9 (developer) are pretty much the same version. 3.8 is simply tied to the [Data Mining book](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/book.html) and doesn't receive new features, only bug fixes. In terms of *stability*, 3.9 is as good as 3.8.

And yes, [python-weka-wrapper3](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3) uses 3.9 under the hood.